# Xamarin.Forms/UWP: issue with Iconize and MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, master-detail, toolbaritems

I use the [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize) plugin for my project, and there is an issue that occurs in case of the IconToolbarItem is used in a IconNavigationPage, that is itself used in the Detail of a MasterDetailPage.

If we launch the UWP project from [IconizeSample](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize/tree/master/samples), the IconToolbarItems are well displayed in the **TabbedPage**:

```
var tabbedPage = new IconTabbedPage { Title = "Iconize" };
foreach (var module in Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Modules)
{
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page1
    {
        BindingContext = new ModuleWrapper(module),
        Icon = module.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
    });
}
MainPage = new IconNavigationPage(tabbedPage);
```

If we replace the TabbedPage by a **MasterDetailPage**, this also works if the Detail is not a IconNavigationPage:

```
var mdPage = new MasterDetailPage();
mdPage.Master = new ContentPage
{
    Title = "Iconize"
};
var module = Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Modules.First();
mdPage.Detail = new Page1
{
    BindingContext = new ModuleWrapper(module),
    Icon = module.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
};
MainPage = new IconNavigationPage(mdPage);
```

But if we put the **Detail** in an **IconNavigationPage**, the icons of the IconToolbarItem are no longer visible:

```
var mdPage = new MasterDetailPage();
mdPage.Master = new ContentPage
{
    Title = "Iconize"
};
var module = Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Modules.First();
mdPage.Detail = new IconNavigationPage(new Page1
{
    BindingContext = new ModuleWrapper(module),
    Icon = module.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
});
MainPage = mdPage;
```

***Would you have an explanation? Is there a way to fix this awaiting a new package version?***

Answer (score 0):

> But if we put the Detail in an IconNavigationPage, the icons of the IconToolbarItem are no longer visible:

The problem is that you have not inserted the `mdPage` into `IconNavigationPage`. I have modified your code and it works.

```
var mdPage = new MasterDetailPage();
mdPage.Master = new ContentPage
{
    Title = "Iconize"
};
var module = Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Modules.First();
var page = new Page1
{
    BindingContext = new ModuleWrapper(module),
    Icon = module.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
};
mdPage.Detail = page;
MainPage = new IconNavigationPage(mdPage);
```

Comment: Hi @Nico Zhu.
I've also made this test in the second case that I've described. It works on UWP but not on Android.

But in the real project where I want to use Iconize, this implementation is not possible. So I wanted to create a test that reproduce the "real" context.

Comment: Yep, I have tried to  replace `ToolbarItem ` with `IconToolbarItem`, it works fine, I think it is  Iconize plugin bug.  I strongly suggest using `ToolbarItem` in your real project.

Comment: I'm working on an existing projet, where the `ToolbarItems` are already implemnted, but only with labels, no with icons. In the new sceens, there are now icons: so Iconize was a good choice to implement this easily. As it seems to work fine on Android and iOS, I think that I will keep this as that. The `IconToolbarItems` display the label on UWP: only the icons are missing.